# maintain or retain the state of a radio-toggled div blocks after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my form there are two radio buttons - when the radio is selected - the div appears, when another one is selected - the div hides. After submitting a form if I go back to form page by clicking browser back button, it hides the div section . I want to retain the states of the div and radio button when page is refresh or when I go back - how to make it work ?
Here is my code -

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(){
        var ac = document.getElementById("ac");
        var page_link= document.getElementById("page_link");
        page_link.style.display = ac.checked ? "block" : "none";       
    }


HTML code 
  <input type="radio" id="ac" name = "mode"  style="margin-left: 130px;" value = "abc"  onclick="ShowHideDiv()" > abc
  <input type="radio" id="mo" name = "mode"  style="margin-left: 10px;" value="xyz" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" checked> xyz

<div id="page_link" style="display: none;">
Hello How are you !!
</div>
```

Comment: where is the rest of the code - the function shows/hides `div` elements which are nowhere to be seen. Basically you need a storage mechanism - the easiest would be `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`

Comment: Edited the code .. <div> tag added
how do i implement sessionStorage or localStorage with this code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to work it into your existing code here is an example of how you might use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` - there are quite a few comments which should help you identify what is going on and to highlight the important pieces you could cherrypick for your own usage.

```
<h1>Tabs & sessionStorage</h1>
<div id='tabs'>
    <div id='t1' data-title='Tab 1'>
        <section>
            <p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p>
            <p>Morbi nec quam sit amet libero hendrerit malesuada nec nec orci. Quisque sapien nibh, suscipit efficitur sem vitae, vulputate vestibulum quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc vel mauris lacinia lorem dictum vestibulum ut id libero. Vivamus fringilla nulla vitae nulla cursus, tristique ultrices velit viverra. Aliquam suscipit dapibus arcu a consequat. Pellentesque quis neque at orci vestibulum faucibus. Nam quis efficitur elit, eu aliquam magna. Ut sagittis sem vitae dui lobortis tincidunt. Aenean ut lorem ac erat fringilla lacinia vel ac nisl.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id='t2' data-title='Tab 2'>
        <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
    </div>
    <div id='t3' data-title='Tab 3'>
        <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
    </div>
    <div id='t4' data-title='Tab 4'>
        <section><p>Aliquam dapibus convallis volutpat. Vestibulum urna lacus, tempor vel diam nec, viverra gravida est. Integer pharetra tincidunt nisi, ut egestas neque porttitor ut. Quisque ut consequat erat, a accumsan ligula. Maecenas ut placerat nunc. Aliquam finibus ligula ac ex hendrerit, quis blandit sapien sollicitudin. Donec ac velit quis sapien gravida efficitur efficitur eu purus. Etiam non risus mattis, consequat diam in, commodo tellus. </p></section>
    </div>
</div>



<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* The name of the storage Item */
    var store='tabs';

    /* a class name used to identify active tab */
    var cn='active';

    /* current value of the storage item, if any */
    var cval=sessionStorage.getItem( store );

    /* A nodelist of tabs within container */
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('div#tabs > div');

    /* Iterate through nodelist */
    for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ){

        /* assign click event handler */
        col[ n ].onclick=function(event){
            /* get reference to current node ( tab ) */
            var el=typeof( event.target )!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;

            /* set the value into storage item */
            sessionStorage.setItem( store, el.id );

            /* assign class to active and remove from inactive nodes */
            for( var m in col ){
                if( col[m].nodeType==1 ){
                    if( col[m].id==el.id )col[m].classList.add( cn );
                    else col[m].classList.remove( cn );
                }
            }
        }

        /* on load, assign active class to the correct tab */
        if( cval!=null && cval==col[n].id ) col[n].classList.add( cn );
    }
</script>
```